Как найти середину закругленного угла?
Есть контур прямоугольника с закругленными углами. Как можно найти устредненные координаты его top-left и bottom-left углов?

Я сделал так:
sum = np.sum(cnt, axis=-1)
tl = cnt[np.argmin(sum)]
diff = np.diff(cnt, axis=-1)
bl = cnt[np.argmax(diff)]

Код выше найдет углы, как показанно на второй фигуре. Но как найти центры углов, даже если фигура может быть повернута?

Как представлен контур?

@MBo, функция cv2.findContours() устанавливает начальную точку ту, которая первой встретится в бинарном изображении, функция обходит его слева направо сверху вниз. Остальные точки отсортированы против часовой.

Вижу, что ответ уже получили. Но, возможно, где-то пригодится обнаружение прямых HoughLines

Точки, показанные слева, отстоят от сторон на расстояние r*(1-SQRT(2)/2), где r - радиус закругления.
Если есть только массив с точками контура, то для начала нужно пройтись по массиву и найти точки сторон. Три точки лежат на одной стороне, если в парах dx = dy. Потом найти крайние точки сторон, а уже по крайним точкам сторон найти для каждой пары точку посередине между ними в массиве.
Можно даже сделать быстрее. Наверняка, начальная точка в массиве привязана к чему-то. Пусть это будет нижяя точка на правом рисунке. И направление обхода контура тоже известно, пусть будет по часовой стрелке.
Тогда для первой же пары точек определяем синус dy1 и косинус dx1. Касательная в искомой точке будет наклонена к стороне под 45 градусов (пи/4) в минус (по часовой). Т. е. идём дальше по массиву и ищем пару точек с dy2=sin(arcsin(dy1)-pi/4) и dx2=cos(arccos(dx1)-pi/4). Одну из этих точек можно взять как искомую. Следующие три пары точек ищем с поворотом на 90 (пи/2), т. е. (dx,dy): (-dу2,dх2), (-dx2,-dy2) и (dy2,-dx2).
Поскольку dx2 и dy2 в точности не найдутся, нужно рассматривать тройки точек, чтобы искомые величины лежали между парами соответствующих. И про экстремумы помнить.
Как определить, что три точки (x1,y1), (x2,y2) и (x3,y3) лежат на одной прямой?
Выражение должно быть истинно:
(x3 >= x2 >= x1 or x3 <= x2 <= x1) and
((x2 - x1) == 0 and (x3 - x2) == 0 or (x2 - x1) != 0 and
    (x3 - x2) != 0 and (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) == (y3 - y2)/(x3 - x2))


Я сейчас понял, что искать именно центр мне не обязательно. Мне достаточно будет крайних точек сторон. Я не очень разбираюсь в математике, можете поподробнее объяснить как их найти? Вы написали, что нужно пройтись по массиву и найти точки сторон. Но как понять, что точка принадлежит именно левой стороне? Условия все те же, фигура может быть как и повернутой вправо или лево, так и стоять ровно.

Ок, чуть позже.

Как задан контур в массиве точек: какая начальная точка, каково направление обхода?

Функция cv2.findContours() устанавливает начальную точку ту, которая первой встретится в бинарном изображении, функция обходит его слева направо сверху вниз. То есть начальная точка будет разной, зависит от поворота фигуры. Далее от начальной точки остальные идут против часовой.

Я алгоритм и математику расписал. Начинаем с первых трёх точек и ползём дальше по одной. Если три точки - сторона, то дальше по четвёртому абзацу.

Если средние точки искать ненужно, а только крайние сторон, то по dx1 и dy1 вычисляем остальные стороны (-dу1,dх1), (-dx1,-dy1) и (dy1,-dx1).  После того, как нашли первую сторону, идём по массиву, и как только  dy/dx начинает менятся - значит это конец строны. Как только dy/dx становиться равно -dу1/dх1 - это начало следующей стороны. И так далее.

Короче, пройдись по массиву, распечатай dy/dx для каждой пары точек, и увидишь.

Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Да, попробуй, а потом пиши, если что.
